# Trying to create a .dekstop file for an .sh

Tags: bash, scripts, password, sh, gksu

I'm trying to create a .desktop file that runs an sh file that reboots my system in Windows 10.
It goes like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Windows 10
Comment=Windows 10
Keywords=w10,windows
Exec=sh /home/jd/.wreboot/w10reboot.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/jd/.wreboot/w10.png
Type=Application
Categories=Utilities;
StartupNotify=false
Version=1.0
```

That desktop file calls this sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu grub-reboot 1 &&
gksu reboot now
```

The problem is I get prompted my password twice and that's annoying.
My knowledge is limited and what I'm trying to do is to prevent the script for asking my password twice. I'd rather not use gksu but it's the only solution I found.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The password is asked twice since you've used `gksu` twice. Try `gksu sh -c "grub-reboot 1 && reboot now"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add special permission for your script to the sudoers file in `/etc/sudoers`

I guess `jd` is your username, if not replace with yours.

add : `%jd ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/jd/.wreboot/w10reboot.sh` to `/etc/sudoers`

Edit your script

```
#!/bin/bash
grub-reboot 1
reboot now
```

Then edit your the `Exec` part of the `.desktop` file as follow

```
Exec=sudo /home/jd/.wreboot/w10reboot.sh
```

Now it should works.

Comment: If the sudo is used in `Exec`, there is no point of using `gksu` is script. Also, did you mean `sudo sh` instead of `sh sudo`?

Comment: That's true, if you use `sudo` to start the script you don't need `gksu`. You're right I made a mistake, it's `sudo sh` instead of `sh sudo`. In fact `sh` is not needed, just use `sudo`

Comment: It was as easy as changing the exec for this

Exec=gksu sh /home/jd/.wreboot/w10reboot.sh

and removing gksu from the sh file
Thanks a lot.